# What kind of relay / switch is this?

Tags: switches, relay, solid-state-relay, solenoid, contact

What kind of relay, if I'm right, is this? It is used in a PRCD.

Pictures from 3 sides.

[image]

Comment: PRCD? Portable Residual Current Device?

Comment: It looks like when enough current goes through the solenoid it retracts and releases the latch allowing the contacts to separate.  I don't have experience with these so leaving a comment rather than answer.

Comment: Dear Evildemonic, thank you. Yes it's in a Portable Residual Current Device.

Comment: Where can I find datasheet or manufacturers of this or like this component? Thank you.

Comment: This gives some information:  https://hackaday.io/project/185382-rccb-prcd-tutorial-working-and-testing-of-plug

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful. 
Where can I find datasheet or manufacturers of the relay?